# Populating a child router-outlet Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router, angular2-template

Since I heard Angular's Router supports nested <router-outlet> tags, I'm trying to use two of them. I"m using the latest Angular-CLI, converting from ui-router to Angular's Router. I can't get the second router-outlet to populate content.

(The parent routing is working fine)
app-routing.module.ts

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'login', pathMatch: 'full', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: DashboardComponent // this holds the second router-outlet
    },
    { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.ts -- this just holds the router-outlet, and works fine at the top level...

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

### The dashboard holds universal headers, footers, sidebars, etc. So that's why I want it in the top-level router-outlet. The sub-router-outlet will populate child views, but doesn't populate.

Attempt 1 dashboard-routing.module.ts

```
export const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' },
    { path: 'home', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'about', pathMatch: 'full', component: AboutComponent }
]
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Attempt 2 dashboard-routing.module.ts as per [Angular2 : Multiple Router-Outlets & Router-Outlets Inside Child Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145140/angular2-multiple-router-outlets-router-outlets-inside-child-route)

```
export const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        children:[
            { path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
            { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent}
        ]
    }
 ]
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Inside the Dashboard template, this nested router-outlet does not populate. Instead, the top-level router-outlet in the app.component.html is populated instead :(

dashboard.component.html

```
<header>...</header>
<aside class="sidenav">...<aside>

<!-- why can't I populate you? -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

#### ************** Answer, a great thank you to [PierreDuc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3106920/pierreduc)! **************

app-routing.module.ts

```
// seems counter-intuitive that the dashboard component isn't actually in here..., but it works!
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'login', pathMatch: 'full', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        DashboardRoutingModule // this is the magic. I'm assuming to put it second is better (though putting it first didn't seem to have any immediate negative effect)
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

dashboard-routing.module.ts

```
export const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children:[
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'home', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'about', pathMatch: 'full', component: AboutComponent }
        ]
    }
]
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Here's how to navigate from the root:

login.component.ts

```
... passed validation ...
this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
this._router.navigate(['/dashboard/home']);
```

or routing via routerLink via a sidebar in the Dashboard
dashboard.component.html

```
[routerLink]="['../login']" <!-- back to login, though the '../' seems less than ideal
```

or in the dashboard view via routerLink to child router-outlets:
dashboard.component.html:

```
[routerLink]="['../about']"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Child `router-outlet`s are populated with the `children` array inside the router configuration. But there's duplication going on. You should remove the `dashboard` entry inside your `AppRoutingModule`, and go for attempt 2:

*app-routes*

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'login', pathMatch: 'full', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

And keep your `DashboardRoutingModule` as is it is in attempt 2 (with the children array), and import this module either inside the `AppRoutingModule`, or in the `AppModule`.

Comment: Wow! That did it! I'll add the code below my question

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much! Now there is a slight non-ideal side effect you might know -- navigation via .navigate or routerLink requires me to use '../' to go back to dashboard, then to the route.  Do you know how to set it up so I don't have to use the relative path traversal back, and just simply navigate to the route name?  Thanks!

Comment: I believe there is no way to do it, besides using the relative path. I'm not entirely sure, but I guess you can also try to navigate to `/dashboard`. The reason it's like that, is because this will give room for child routes to be the same name as parent routes: `dashboard/client/dashboard`. Now if you were in `client`, how would you navigate to `dashboard` without ambiguity :)?